# Imprimir datos de consulta sql en laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel, relaciones

Tengo 4 tablas, MEDICOS, USERS, ROLE_USER y ROLE.

Medicos hereda como foranea el ID de Users y a su ves, Users y Role, tienen una relacion de muchos a muchos usando como tabla pivote ROLE_USER.

Desde los modelos estan relacionados tengo las relacion correcta de Users y Role y tambien de Users y Medicos.

Tengo esta consulta.

```
$Medicos=Medicos::join("Users","Medicos.user_id","=","Users.id")
    ->join("Role_User","Users.id","Role_User.User_id")
    ->join('Roles',"Role_User.id","Roles.id")
    ->where('users.estado','=',1)
    ->get();
```

Al hacer la consulta me devuelve solo 3 Medicos.

```
(3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
 0: {ID: 1, centromedico_id: 1, user_id: 1, especialidad_id: 1, nombre: "Aldahir", …}
 1: {ID: 2, centromedico_id: 2, user_id: 2, especialidad_id: 2, nombre: "Marlyn Isamar", …}
 2: {ID: 3, centromedico_id: 1, user_id: 3, especialidad_id: 2, nombre: "Pablo Alberto", …}
```

Pero en realidad tengo 5 Medicos registrados, y solo me devuelve los primeros 3, uno por cada medico que tengo registrado.

Quizas sea la relacion de los modelos.

Modelo Role... tiene una relacion de muchos a muchos con users, esta es la relacion.

```
public function users(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role');
}
```

Modelo Users... tiene una relacion de muchos a muchos con Role, y una relacion de uno a uno con Medicos

```
public function roles(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role');
}
public function Medicos(){
    return $this->hasOne('App\Medicos', 'user_id', 'id');
}
```

Modelo Medicos tiene una relacion inversa de 1 a 1 con Users.

```
public function User(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user_id', 'id');
}
```

Cuando ocupo la consulta que tengo me arroja una relacion, si, pero solo 1 por cada Role existente.

1
ID: 1
...
estado: 1
id: 1
...
role: "Administrador"
role_id: 1

2
ID: 2
...
estado: 1
id: 2
...
role: "Secretaria"
role_id: 2
3
ID: 3
...
estado: 1
id: 3
...
role: "Medico"
role_id: 3

Comment: Tenés definidas todas las relaciones en los modelos de cada una de las tablas?

Comment: Acabo de actualizar la pregunta, si hay alguna forma de hacer la consulta con eloquent en lugar del constructor igual me gustaria saberlo

Comment: Intenta con leftJoin